# std::reference_wrapper and polymorphic containers

Tags: c++, polymorphism, containers, reference-wrapper

I am trying to make a polymorphic vector using `std::reference_wrapper` for these classes:

```
struct Int2TypeBase{
    virtual void which(){ std::cout << "Int2TypeBase" << "\n";}
};


template <int v>
struct Int2Type : public Int2TypeBase
{
    enum
    {
        value = v
    };

    void which(){ std::cout << "Int2Type<" << value  << ">""\n";}

    friend bool operator==(const Int2Type& lhs, const Int2Type& rhs){
        return lhs.v == rhs.v;
    }
};
```

Now I am trying to make use of `std::reference_wrapper` like this:

```
int main(){
    using namespace std;

    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Int2TypeBase>> v;

    Int2Type<0> i2t_1;
    v.emplace_back(i2t_1);

    auto x = v[0];
    x.get().which();

    std::cout << typeid(x.get()).name() << "\n";

    // std::cout << (x.get() == i2t_1) << "\n";
}
```

The output is:

```
Int2Type<0>
8Int2TypeILi0EE
```

This is what I would expect.

Now however, when I uncomment `std::cout << (x.get() == i2t_1) << "\n";` I will get

```
invalid operands to binary expression ('Int2TypeBase' and 'Int2Type<0>')
```

This confuses me, as `typeid(x.get()).name()` returned `8Int2TypeILi0EE` rather than `F12Int2TypeBasevE` which is what I get for `typeid(Int2TypeBase()).name();`. Furthermore `which()` also was called for the derived class... so then why does `x.get()` in `x.get() == i2t_1` evaluate to a `Int2TypeBase`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At compile time, the compiler can only tell that the type of x.get() is Int2TypeBase, because as declared you can put any Int2TypeBase there.  So at compile time, it can't determine that the == operator will work.

At run time, the objects you put in the collection reference their full type, so typeid returns what you expect and the correct virtual function is called.

Comment: Is there another way to get the type of the derived objects at compile time?

Comment: @lotolmencre -- No, it's actually impossible.  When your collection is declared as holding a base type, it may contain any derived type as far as the compiler is concerned.  Anything you want to do that's determined by the full type has to be a virtual method (or use some other form of dynamic dispatch)

Answer (score 2):

Your comparison operator is only defined for derived classes, but the reference wrapper produces (static) type `Int2Base`, so overload resolution does not even *find* your comparison operator!

What you probably need is a comparison operator of the form

```
bool operator==(const Int2TypeBase& lhs, const Int2TypeBase& rhs)
```

but then you also need to have some sort of polymorphic dispatch to perform the actual comparison (presumably assuming that the dynamic types match).