# Alternative to overloading functions with derived types

Tags: c++, polymorphism, derived-class, overloading

Sorry for the uninformative title, I don't really know what to call what I am asking.

I want to achieve the following: Having a container of a base class type with instances of derived types, accessing the containers and calling a function overload dependent on the type of the derived object accessed. In a question earlier I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42449620/stdreference-wrapper-and-polymorphic-containers) I learned that the static design I had in mind so far, does not work. The way I tried is this:

```
struct Int2TypeBase{
};

template <int v>
struct Int2Type : public Int2TypeBase
{
    enum
    {
        value = v
    };
};


void f(const Int2Type<0>&){
    std::cout << "f(const Int2Type<0>&)" << "\n";
}

void f(const Int2Type<1>&){
    std::cout << "f(const Int2Type<1>&)" << "\n";
}


int main(){
    using namespace std;

    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Int2TypeBase>> v;

    Int2Type<0> i2t_1;
    v.emplace_back(i2t_1);
    Int2Type<1> i2t_2;
    v.emplace_back(i2t_2);

    auto x0 = v[0];
    auto x1 = v[1];

    f(x0.get());                // After my imagination this would have called void f(const Int2Type<0>&)
    f(x1.get());                // After my imagination this would have called void f(const Int2Type<1>&)
}
```

Ok, so I want the correct overload of `f` to be selected, this however does not compile as at compile time it is unknown which type `x0` and `x1` actually have. But is there some alternate design that can realize this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Overloading is a static mechanism based on static types.

If you want to change behaviour *dynamically* based on the *dynamic type* of an object, C++ provides another built-in language feature for that: Virtual functions. Use them like this:

```
struct Int2TypeBase
{
    virtual void do_f() = 0;
};

template <int v> struct Int2Type : Int2TypeBase
{
    void do_f() override
    {
         // specific behaviour for Int2Type<v> goes here
    }

    /* ... */
};

void f(Int2TypeBase & x) { x.do_f(); }
```

Now you can call `f` on any base subobject and the correct behaviour is selected at runtime. In particular, `f(x0.get())` and `f(x1.get())` now select and dispatch to `Int2Type<0>::do_f` and `Int2Type<1>::do_f` at runtime, respectively.

Comment: unfortunately not applicable to my situation, as in reality the `f`-functions have different return types.

Comment: @lotolmencre: Regrettably your question was keeping this new requirement a secret...

Comment: yea, I did not think of it when I built the minimal working example.